# Can you personalise Additional Email Attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have additional email attributes enabled.

Is it possible to send personalised string with in additional attribute e:g a value from data extension.

I tried v(@deField) but it goes empty in email and it not returning any error though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, the OMM (the scripting pre-processor) doesn't run again after the links are wrapped.  I've tried to work around this in the past, but SFMC Support confirmed that it won't work.